# How do I replicate a square in GLSL to make a pattern?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shapes, fragment-shader, tile

I am learning how to create shapes in GLSL code and I recently made a star-like shape in the center of a square using the following code:

```
#idef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_time;


void main(){
  vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
  st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
  vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
  float d = 0.0;

  // Remap space to -1 to 1.
  st = st *2.-1.;

  // Make Distance Field
  d = length(abs(st)-.3);
  d = length(min(abs(st)-.3, 0.));

  // Visualize the Distance Field
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(fract(d*10.0)), 1.0);

  // Draw with the distance field
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(step(.3, d)), 1.0);

}
```

I now want to try to replicate this square design into a bordered tile-like pattern but I don't know how to modify my code to duplicate it into columns. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scale `st` by the number of tiles and get the fractional part of the result by [`fract()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/fract.xhtml). For instance:

```c
void main()
{
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
    
    float tiles = 5.0;
    st = fract(st * tiles);

    // [...]
}
```

---

In your example you have to adapt the computation of the distance filed slightly (`0.3` -> `0.32`):

```c
// Make Distance Field
d = length(abs(st)-.32);
d = length(min(abs(st)-.32, 0.));
```

---

See the WebGL example using the fragment shader from your question:

```js
(function loadscene() {    

var canvas, gl, vp_size, prog, bufObj = {};

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "ogl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = gl.createProgram();
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        let source = document.getElementById(i==0 ? "draw-shader-vs" : "draw-shader-fs").text;
        let shaderObj = gl.createShader(i==0 ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
        gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
        let status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
        gl.attachShader(progDraw, shaderObj);
        gl.linkProgram(progDraw);
    }
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(progDraw, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(progDraw));
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation(progDraw, "inPos");
    progDraw.u_time = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_time");
    progDraw.u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_resolution");
    gl.useProgram(progDraw);

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    //vp_size = [256, 256]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function render(deltaMS) {

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_time, deltaMS/1000.0);
    gl.uniform2f(progDraw.u_resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
#version 100
//precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;

//varying vec2 ndcPos;

void main()
{
    //ndcPos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

//varying vec2 ndcPos;  // normaliced device coordinates in range [-1.0, 1.0]
uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main()
{
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
    
    float tiles = 5.0;
    st = fract(st * tiles);
    
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    float d = 0.0;

    // Remap space to -1 to 1.
    st = st *2.-1.;

    // Make Distance Field
    d = length(abs(st)-.32);
    d = length(min(abs(st)-.32, 0.));

    // Visualize the Distance Field
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(fract(d*10.0)), 1.0);

    // Draw with the distance field
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(step(.3, d)), 1.0);
}
</script>

<canvas id="ogl-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: When I tried my code with your modifications, it created a series of tiles but the star wasn't in the center of them. Did I don something wrong?

Comment: @Garrus What do you mean by *"the star wasn't in the center of them"*? Of course they are centered if the texture coordinates are in range [0.0, 1.0].